# Running Android Application on Real Device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my Android App on a real android phone. I've done this previously, but now I have a different android phone I want to connect. The phone is a HTC Wildfire A3333 - Android Version 2.2.1 (old I know)... if that's any help.

I have connected the device and shows up in the Windows device manager..

[image]

I've connected the driver for the phone within the manager, in the same location that worked previously for me (`sdkhome\extras\google\usb_driver\i386`) and it always says the driver is up-to date.

I just can't get it to appear in the android device list at all!

[image]

Even after killing the adb sever and starting it again, it comes up with the connected device in command prompt but still doesn't show in the android device chooser. I've restarted my PC and reconnected the phone many times.

[image]

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: is usb debugging enabled?

Comment: Did you try disconnecting the cable from the phone and connecting it again?

Comment: Either use newer version device or lower minSdkVersion of your application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@ecrip

Dude your app needs `2.3.6 [GingerBread API 10]` minimum target but you have a`2.2.1(Froyo API 8)` device as you said

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

In your prompt its asking for API 10 
you have `android 2.2.1(Froyo API 8)` as you said so its not listing it here but showing in command `prompt` this is the problem

### Solution

**Either use newer version device or lower minSdkVersion of your application**

@ecrip if adb is listed on command then make sure the min sdk or your application must be less than or equal to your device api version

This is very common issue with adb
The most common solution if it suddenly `stop showing` connected device or make it `offline` and never become `online`
Then

`Restart Eclipse`

or `Reboot System`

## Alternatively

if usb debugging is enable do this 
on command prompt move to **<sdk>/platform-tools**

```
adb kill-server

adb start-server

adb devices
```

### Note:

1. In my `cmd` i am directly commanding `adb` cause i have set the **adb path** to `Environmental Variable`
2. If you know the Device ip connected to pc then you can connect it using the following

   #### adb connect <Your iP address>

[image]

---

if usb-debugging is desabled do one of  following

Keep usb debugging enabled on you Android device 
For Android 2.3.6

### Settings >> Application Settings >> Development

For Android 4.2 Tab

### Dev Settings

[image]

[image: For Android 2.3.6]

Comment: Hmm. It's very strange, I've restarted everything. I have killed the server and started it like your post says and when I run the "adb devices" it lists my device I believe. However when I run my application from my IDE it doesn't appear in the Android Device Chooser?

Comment: i face too these problem suddenly it shows offline and disappear from list then reboot works

Comment: whats that does it belongs to this question

Comment: @photon this looks to good to add another answer.  The wildfire is gingerbread so are you targeting back to that version of Android?  The first time debugging on a physical phone is always a bear don't give up visit manufactures website for recent drivers.

Comment: Any more ideas guys? Appears in the adb list on command prompt but i can't choose it when running my application

Comment: @twntee: what to do with that

Comment: @ecirp why don't you debug using command prompt and you should mention this fact to your question this will help people for better answer

Comment: @ecirp what's device android version

Comment: HTC Wildfire A3333 - Android Version 2.2.1 (old I know).

Comment: you can't, see updated answer, you must lower the min sdk for your device

Comment: AHH you are right. I had to change the <uses-sdk> android:minSdkVersion="8" and then it appears like magic! thankyou