# Not able to run my first program on android tablet

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I am not able to run on my android tablet. I have been following the [Android training link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)
It says

To run the app from Eclipse:

1. Open one of your project's files and click Run  from the toolbar.
2. In the Run as window that appears, select Android Application and click OK.

But when I do the same , I do not see anything on my Motorola Xoom Tablet.

I have checked the following link  for [Setting up USB drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html). As per the link , I have confirmed that device is connected.

*When plugged in over USB, you can verify that your device is connected by executing adb devices from your SDK platform-tools/ directory. If connected, you'll see the device name listed as a "device."*

```
C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
0380610842bf5157        device
```

Can anyone please advise where I am going wrong. What should I do to make my eclipse code run on android tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. I got this beautiful well detailed answer which resolved the issue

[Actual Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10612622/392233)

Answer (score 2):

Do this

### Click on The Project Root Folder >> Run as Android Project >> A device selection window will appear

Now select your device it will install application and start it

**Note:** as per your project setup

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

#### Your device must have API Level >= 8

OR

You can take help from my answer here In which i have talked about several possibilities
[Running Android Application on Real Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553394/running-android-application-on-real-device)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was all a matter of finding the right window in Eclipse.

Click "Window" -> "Show View" -> "Project Explorer".
Then right click "MyFirstApp" from the menu on the left, then click "Run as" -> "Android application".